# Back Press From the Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, popup

I have one query and need help regrading it.

I have two Fragment in my app, let say  Fragment A and Fragment B , when my app opens Fragment A will appear first (and it contain one button while pressing button it call fragment B ).Now Fragment B contains one Button (let's say Button C),while pressing Button C the popwindow will appear.

Problem i am facing ,when i back press from the Fragment B, the popwindow dismissing ,that working fine but it loading fragment A.

I don't want to load Fragment A on Back Press. On Back Press ,if pop window is showing then it should dismiss and remain in fragment B and if popwindow is not showing then it should go out of the app.

I tried : I created the interface in fragment B and getting the instance of the popwindow in Activity.

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();

        if(popupWindow!=null && popupWindow.isShowing()){
            popupWindow.dismiss();
            backpopwindow.dismiss();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onHandleRequest(PopupWindow popupWindow, PopupWindow backpopwindow, String fragmentName) {
        if (fragmentName != null) {
            this.fragmentName = fragmentName;
            if (popupWindow != null) {
                this.popupWindow = popupWindow;
                this.backpopwindow = backpopwindow;

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: hide  super.onBackPressed(); and run.

Comment: else condition call getActivity().finish(); .It should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {  

  if(popupWindow!=null && popupWindow.isShowing()){
     popupWindow.dismiss();
     backpopwindow.dismiss();
  } else {
    finish();
  }
}
```

This will close the popupWindow if it is visible, or else finish the activity

Answer (score 1):

You can try this, it will work for back stack with Fragment B and popup window also.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    //super.onBackPressed();

    if(popupWindow!=null && popupWindow.isShowing()){
        popupWindow.dismiss();
        //backpopwindow.dismiss();
        return;
    }

    if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0)
    {
        getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();

    }
    else
    {
        finish();
    }
}
```